# How can I make 5 column in 1 row with jumbotron bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component

I get reference from here : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/jumbotron/

My script like this :

```
<b-row>
  <b-col cols>
    <b-jumbotron header="Bootstrap 4" lead="Bootstrap 4 Components for Vue.js 2">
      <p>For more information visit website</p>
      <b-btn variant="primary" href="#">More Info</b-btn>
    </b-jumbotron>
  </b-col>
  <b-col cols>
    <b-jumbotron header="Bootstrap 4" lead="Bootstrap 4 Components for Vue.js 2">
      <p>For more information visit website</p>
      <b-btn variant="primary" href="#">More Info</b-btn>
    </b-jumbotron>
  </b-col>
  <b-col cols>
    <b-jumbotron header="Bootstrap 4" lead="Bootstrap 4 Components for Vue.js 2">
      <p>For more information visit website</p>
      <b-btn variant="primary" href="#">More Info</b-btn>
    </b-jumbotron>
  </b-col>
  <b-col cols>
    <b-jumbotron header="Bootstrap 4" lead="Bootstrap 4 Components for Vue.js 2">
      <p>For more information visit website</p>
      <b-btn variant="primary" href="#">More Info</b-btn>
    </b-jumbotron>
  </b-col>
  <b-col cols>
    <b-jumbotron header="Bootstrap 4" lead="Bootstrap 4 Components for Vue.js 2">
      <p>For more information visit website</p>
      <b-btn variant="primary" href="#">More Info</b-btn>
    </b-jumbotron>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

If the script executed, in 1 row there are only 2 columns. Should there exist 5 column

Can I set jumbroton so that in 1 row there are 5 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep everything on one line with

```
.row {
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.col {
 min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems it works. I want to ask again. Can the height of jumbroton be set? I want to set it up. Besides that I want to set padding too

Comment: Can be done from css... check jumbotron classes and apply your desidered height

Comment: I don't want to change the original CSS. Can it override the css? Besides that I want to add a image

Comment: Customize the jumbotron from your vue component

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot